# Sonarqube Scan Language is forced

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Having issue for 6.7.1 wherein the SonarScanner is forcing languages to be analysis-ed for languages other than the defined

> e.g. sonar.language=xml

And the analysis will:

> INFO: Language is forced to xml
>
> INFO: Language is forced to java

Why is this and how can I force the sonarscanner to only analysis for one language?

NOTE: Have tested in 5.5 and this dosn't seem to be occuring.

Comment: try to delete all  files which sonar generates during analyse. .scannerwork  under project and  ~/.sonar in your home directory. If you are under windows check if there is not any old sonar scanner process running. I have tried this functionality with sonar version 7 and it works as expected.

Comment: Note that `sonar.language` has been _deprecated_ for quite a while now.

Comment: Ann, this should be metioned here https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Comment: So G. Ann, what version of Sonar has it been deprecated since?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam what is the alternative to the sonar.language property ?